# Compiling ASP.NET pages on server

Tags: asp.net, compilation

Is there any way how I can compile files that are already uploaded on FTP ? I wwould like to run the compilation process from the server side .

Thank you very much

Comment: is it shared host or dedicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx) is your friend and teacher.

> "Any changes to a dynamically compiled file will automatically
>   invalidate the file's cached compiled assembly and trigger
>   recompilation of all affected resources. The next time a request to
>   the code is made, ASP.NET recognizes that the code has changed and
>   recompiles the affected resources of the Web application. This system
>   enables you to quickly develop applications with a minimum of
>   compilation processing overhead. (Note that depending on the change to
>   the resources, the result can range from recompiling a single page to
>   recompiling the whole Web site.)"

Answer (score -1):

```
csc /t:library /out:MyCodeLibrary.dll simpleType.cs
```

Comment: You have a .Net development on your production server ...?

Comment: @5arx, How you wanna compile without compiler?